# React Outlook Add-in localhost not reachable from Mobile device (iOS)

Tags: iphone, webpack-dev-server, outlook-web-addins, windows-firewall

I developed an Outlook add-in which is working fine in all instances of Outlook on Prem as Outlook OTW. We are using webpack for setting up the current server and changed the host to 0.0.0.0 to expose the development webserver to the network.

The Webserver is reachable for my mobile device over the browser but as soon as I try to startup the developed outlook add-in which gets shown and everything. I get the notification that the server is not reachable and this may be a network problem.

Like i said the server is reachable i can ping my IPhone over the command line and everything except for the Outlook mobile app.

If i set the SourceLocation in the manifest to be our hosted dev server the Outlook add-in is working like it's supposed to be. But I need to get it work on the local host too. Did anybody face same issues and managed to fix it for local development of an Outlook add-in which is also working on mobile devices?

I did set the MobileFormFactor in the manifest and changed the urls to my computers network address and changed the dev server startup with --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000.

Thanks in advance for every help provided. I'm searching for a solution several days.

Comment: Are you able to reach your local web server from any browser on the mobile device?

Comment: Have you tried using tools like `ngrok` for that?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes we are able to reach the local web server via the safari and other browsers. We may have found the solution the dev certificates are not the right ones if you change to your ip address instead of using local host. At monday i will try to create own certs for the ip address instead.

Comment: I think you are on the right avenue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to get the localhost exposed and accessable over outlook mobile app via adding an own dev-certificate for SSL [I fixed the issue with ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started/). Now it's working fine and is accessable and testable.

Biggest problem so far is that you need to update the manifest several times if you restart your ngrok server.